# using Toshiba AT300 as Device in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, device

im using a toshiba at320 tablet with android 4.
I cant find any USB OEM Driver to Run Applications from Eclipse.
Is there any Driver available?

best regards

Answer (score 2):

ok that thing works now... on  a better connection. All theese nice shiny thinges around downloading didn't mention something that the file is corrupt.... although filesize differed :-(

On 3G conneciton it is 9 MB in size and it works. Eclipse now shows my tablet (AT300) and runs my  apps from a developer training on the tablet itself and no more on the emulator. So I would consider that as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found a driver download at this site...I can't vouch for the source, but it worked for me
(scroll down past the ads to the actual message post)

http://www.thriveforums.org/forum/toshiba-excite-10-development/11311-adb-drivers-excite-usb-adb-driver-installation-package.html